# Javascript If / Else with simple math not working

Tags: javascript, date, if-statement, math, time

I have this script that gives me the time from the date I entered to the current time in days.

```
var millennium =new Date(2015, 6, 17)
today=new Date()

var one_day=1000*60*60*24

Math.ceil((today.getTime()-millennium.getTime())/(one_day)<2)
document.write(Math.ceil((today.getTime()-millennium.getTime())/(one_day))+
" day ago"
```

It is working fine but I want to have a simple if / else statement that changes the word "days" to "day" when it is only 1 day ago.
I tried this but is's not working:

```
var millennium =new Date(2015, 6, 17)
today=new Date()

var one_day=1000*60*60*24

if(Math.ceil((today.getTime()-millennium.getTime())/(one_day)==1){
document.write(Math.ceil((today.getTime()-millennium.getTime())/(one_day))+
" day ago")
}
else {

 document.write(Math.ceil((today.getTime()-millennium.getTime())/(one_day))+
  " days ago")

 }
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: calculate once; `var x = Math.ceil(...);` then `document.write(x + " day" + (x == 1 ? "" : "s") + " ago"`

Comment: You have one `(` too many. Open the browser's JavaScript console so that you'll see the error messages if you make syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be some typography errors.

A corrected version is:

```
var millennium =new Date(2015, 6, 17);
var today=new Date();
var one_day=1000*60*60*24;
var x = Math.ceil((today.getTime()-millennium.getTime())/one_day)
if(x == 1) { 
    document.write(x + " day ago");
}
else {
   document.write(x + " days ago");
}
```